# Worklight - Persistency data access issue com.worklight.core.exceptions.PersistentDataAccessException: Persistency data access

Tags: db2, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst

We have seen some error logs on the worklight messages.logs we are not able to understand or replicate the scenario, Interestingly all the issues recorded are with respected to WKUHB database, Can anyone please share more information how can we understand the impact of this error on Mobile Apps.

Worklight version used :- 6.1.0.2, DB2 Version :- v9.7.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error log states:

> A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underl ying socket, socket input stream, or socket output stream. ... A remote host did not respond within the timeout period.

You need to check in your network setup why the timeout was reached.
You may also look in your underlying application server for the management of stale connections.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Can you please let us know how do we check for stale connections or how do we overcome this issue, is there something in the settings files which we can configure. Please suggest. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I am not a databases expert nor WAS expert - if this issue is in production, you're supposed to open a PMR and not a stack overflow question. ...